# Non blocking function that preserves order

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, nonblocking

I have the following method:

```
void store(SomeObject o) {  

}
```

The idea of this method is to store `o` to a permanent storage *but* the function should not block. I.e. I can not/must not do the actual storage in the same thread that called `store`.
I can not also start a thread and store the object from the other thread because `store` might be called a "huge" amount of times and I don't want to start spawning threads.
So I options which I don't see how they can work well:
1) Use a thread pool (`Executor` family)
2) In `store` store the object in an array list and return. When the array list reaches e.g. 1000 (random number) then start another thread to "flush" the array list to storage. But I would still possibly have the problem of too many threads (thread pool?)
So in both cases the only requirement I have is that I store persistantly the objects in exactly the same order that was passed to `store`. And using multiple threads mixes things up.
How can this be solved?
How can I ensure:
1) Non blocking `store`
2) Accurate insertion order
3) I don't care about any storage guarantees. If e.g. something crashes I don't care about losing data e.g. cached in the array list before storing them.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a SingleThreadExecutor and a BlockingQueue.

SingleThreadExecutor as the name sais has one single Thread. Use it to poll from the Queue and persist objects, blocking if empty.

You can add not blocking to the queue in your store method.

**EDIT**
Actually, you do not even need that extra Queue - [JavaDoc of newSingleThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) sais:

> Creates an Executor that uses a **single worker thread** operating off an **unbounded queue**. (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

So I think it's exactly what you need.

```
private final ExecutorService persistor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
public void store( final SomeObject o ){
    persistor.submit( new Runnable(){
            @Override public void run(){
                // your persist-code here.
            }
        } );
}
```

The advantage of using a Runnable that has a quasi-endless-loop and using an extra queue would be the possibility to code some "Burst"-functionality. For example you could make it wait to persist only when 10 elements are in queue or the oldest element has been added at least 1 minute ago ...

Comment: Why a blockingqueue and not a concurrentlinkedqueue?

Comment: Because the Thread will block on an empty queue without expensive spin-wait. The choice of the concrete implementation is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Have one separate thread that gets items from the end of a queue (blocking on an empty queue), and writes them to disk. Your main thread's `store()` function just adds items to the beginning of the queue.

Here's a rough idea (though I assume there will be cleaner or faster ways for doing this in production code, depending on how fast you need things to be):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class ObjectWriter implements Runnable {

    private final Object END = new Object();
    BlockingQueue<Object> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

    public void store(Object o) throws InterruptedException {
        queue.put(o);
    }

    public ObjectWriter() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void close() throws InterruptedException {
        queue.put(END);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Object o = queue.take();
                if (o == END) {
                    // close output file.
                    return;
                }

                System.out.println(o.toString()); // serialize as appropriate
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectWriter w = new ObjectWriter();
        w.store("hello");
        w.store("world");
        w.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`?

Comment: `put` blocks on a full queue. By default the maximum queue size is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so in practice it'll be fine. That said, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` sounds like a better fit, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [Chronicle-Queue](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue) which is a library I designed.

It allows you to write in the current thread without blocking. It was originally designed for low latency trading systems.  For small messages it takes around 300 ns to write a message.

You don't need to use a back ground thread, or a on heap queue and it doesn't wait for the data to be written to disk by default. It also ensures consistent order for all readers. If the program dies at any point after you call `finish()` the message is not lost. (Unless the OS crashes/loses power) It also supports replication to avoid data loss.

Comment: Sounds like a very big gun for a very small task…

Comment: @Holger possibly but it will do everything the OP wants, without threads of on heap queues. +1

Answer (score 0):

The comments in your question make it sound like you are unfamilier with multi-threading, but it's really not that difficult.

You simply need another thread responsible for writing to the storage which picks items off a queue. - your `store` function just adds the objects to the in-memory queue and continues on it's way.

Some psuedo-ish code:

```
final List<SomeObject> queue = new List<SomeObject>();

void store(SomeObject o) {
    // add it to the queue - note that modifying o after this will also alter the
    // instance in the queue
    synchronized(queue) {
       queue.add(queue);
       queue.notify();  // tell the storage thread there's something in the queue
    }
}

void storageThread() {
    SomeObject item;
    while (notfinished) {
       synchronized(queue) {
          if (queue.length > 0) {
             item = queue.get(0);  // get from start to ensure same order
             queue.removeAt(0);
          } else {
             // wait for something
             queue.wait();
             continue;
          }
       }

       writeToStorage(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jim I don't think so. Where do you think it is blocked?

Comment: You are synchronizing on the queue.

Comment: That's how multithreading works - you can't have sensible mutlithreading without synchronisation.  Synchronisation !== blocking.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? LinkedBlockingQueue gives you all the blocking and notification for free.

Comment: @Fildor The point was to demonstrate how non-blocked multi-threading works.